# Activity not paused quickly enough

Tags: java, android

In my AppCompatActivity, I am showing an AlertDialog at a specific event.

Once the AlertDialog is shown, the user should not be able to click on anything in my AppCompatActivity anymore.

I tried to disable the activity in onPause(): `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);`

And to check whether it is not paused: `getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)`

But it seems that onPause() is not called quickly enough for that.

I could set a static boolean to true whenever I pause the AppCompatActivity, set it on false in onResume() and check it in every single onClickListener/onTouchListener etc., but is there a better way to do it?

Every help is appreciated!

**Edit:**
Thanks for your comments! I found out, that when I am clicking on the screen while the UI thread is started (for opening the AlertDialog), the click is put in a queue. That's why the click event is executed while the AlertDialog is running. Do I need to save the AlertDialog and check if it is running or is there a better way?

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to achieve or post more code, because showing a dialog - which is modal - does, in fact, prevent you from clicking on things behind it. This is not something you should need to solve.

Comment: Do you mean that the dialog is dismissed when you interact with the activity behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving an instance and writing a method to check if the Activity should not be active:

```
private void canRun() {
    return (dialog == null || !dialog.isShowing()) && getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should let us know more about your code. However, I think that I can guess what you're saying. There is a `setEnabled(false)` method for every view component in android, and if you call it on a view component java object, it'll be disabled and no longer clickable. So you can simply disable your components whenever you want to show the AlertDialog and then enable them again by calling `setEnabled(true)` if you wish. I'm pretty sure pausing the activity is not what you should do. Because doing it manually, is not best practice anyway, at all.